# libqxcb Issue In Anaconda

Tags: anaconda

When I have updated my anaconda through `conda update --all`, now I have the following issue whenever I want to use plot from mathplotlib.

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
```

I googled the issue and I have read some libraries could be missing form libqxcb.so linking

So I ran `ldd libqxcb.so` in two directories: 
(a)`anaconda/plugins/platforms` all looks fine
(b) `anaconda/pkgs/qt-5.6.0-0/plugins/platforms/` followings are not found

```
libicui18n.so.54 => not found
libicuuc.so.54 => not found
libicudata.so.54 => not found
```

They look fine in (a) but not in (b).
Any help?

Here also some versions info from `conda list`:

```
anaconda                  4.2.0
conda                     4.2.9
matplotlib                1.5.3
qt                        5.6.0
qtpy                      1.1.2
python                    3.5.2
pyqt                      5.6.0
```

Comment: I found I can copy `libicudata.so.54, libicuuc.so.54` and `libicui18n.so.54` into directory which `acanaconda/pkgs/qt-5.6.0-0/plugins/platforms/onda/pkgs/qt-5.6.0-0/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so` actaully look. Now there is no complain but still I have got the `This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""` error.

Comment: For time-being I have used `backend : TkAgg` in matplotlibrc and at-least I can see my plots now.